# How can i add an event handler on Gmail sign in button such that that i can store username and password into a local database?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```
form.addEventlistener("submit",
function()
{
    var data = form.elements["Passwd"].value;
    evt.preventDefault();
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({'data':data},
        function(response)
        {
            alert(response);
        });
});
```

> above code is in content script.js which invoke an event on signIn button.

```
function onRequest(request, sender, sendResponse)
{
    sendResponse('password field found'+request.data);
};
```

> above is in background.js which recceives the message from contentscript.js

```
var signup = document.getElementById('signIn');
signup.addEventlistener('onclick', 
    function(evt)
    {
        var val = document.getElementById('Passwd').value;
        evt.preventDefault();
        alert(document.getElementById('Passwd').value);
        chrome.extension.sendRequest({'data':val},
             function(response)
             {
                 alert(response);
             }
    });
```

> Added an event on signIn button in contentscript.js, but it is not working.

Comment: Instead of commenting on your question, you should just update your question with the additional information.

Comment: Sorry! adamdunson, check out i have edited it all over again,

Comment: Here i am trying to invoke an event on clicking of sign in button of http://www.gmail.com, and pass the value of password field into a background.js which is running in background.

Comment: Don't. You should never scrape passwords from a page. If you really, really, really *need* someone's password, have them enter it in a form in an options page so they know explicitly that you are capturing their password. Otherwise you extension is considered malware.

Comment: I don't really want to create any kind of malicious app or extension, i want to employ that password as a mapping  to my gesture authentication scheme so this is small part of an project, And what do you mean with option page can u elaborate.??
Thanx

Comment: Hey! abraham thanx for the help i am able to store the value in local storage but is there any way we can input the value from database to input field of the webpage