# How to make google apps can subscribe to user google account java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Which library API in Java that I should use to make my google apps on google app engine server can subscribe to user's google account. So when the user login to its gmail account, it will send message to my app saying that the user just login to it's gmail.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, a quick search does not find Gmail support for pluggable event handlers, which is what this would need.  Your question is similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20980780/how-can-i-add-an-event-handler-on-gmail-sign-in-button-such-that-that-i-can-stor) that currently has no answer.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your reply. How about the Task Queues API or XMPP API? Is using either of them will work?

Comment: Task queues probably will not help.  The XMPP API would be a way to push a notification to a client of your app, if only you had something to trigger the notification.  Gmail does not seem to have such a trigger option, nor do other webmail systems.  You might be able to build your own front end that sits between the user and Gmail, but it would be lots of work to create and easy to bypass.  I can also imagine Google not even wanting to support your functionality because it risks violations of security and privacy by malicious developers.